# CRLF is not sent during serial communication using Python

Tags: python, communication, micropython

A win10 program running Python 3.7.9 trying to send via serial USB port to an ESP32 REPL running MicroPython.
The program is supposed to do the following:

1. create a file "XXXX.py"
2. write a string "AHFRTG" to the file followed by CRLF
3. write a string "112121 " to the file followed by CRLF
4. close the file

The file gets created, but there is only 1 line containing "AHFRTG112121". **Ie. the CRLF is missing.**

```
import serial 
import time

try:
  portx = "COM6"
  bps = 115200
  timex = 5
  ser = serial.Serial(portx,bps,timeout=timex)
  
  result = ser.write("f = open('XXXX.py','a')\r\n".encode())
  time.sleep(1)
  
  result = ser.write("f.write('AHFRTG')\r\n".encode())
  time.sleep(1)
  
  result = ser.write("f.write('112121')\r\n".encode())
  time.sleep(1)

  result = ser.write("f.close()\r\n".encode())
  time.sleep(1)
  
  print('------------------------')
  ser.close() #Close serial port

except Exception as e:
  print("---abnormal---: ",e)'''
```

Comment: how about r`"f.write('AHFRTG')\r\n"` adding `r`?

Comment: You only have the ``\r\n`` in the *code to write* to the file, not in the *content* written by the code to write to the file. E.g. ``"f.write('AHFRTG')\r\n"`` instead of ``"f.write('AHFRTG\r\n')\r\n"``.

Comment: it seems the OP is sending the multipleline python scripts via serialport. so i think it's the `\r\n` after the code matters.

Comment: When I used: 
 ** ser.write("f.write('AHFRTG\r\n')\r\n".encode())**
that line was not written at all, only the next

Comment: Have you checked what program the micropython must run *without* going through the serial port? Due to universal newlines, ``f.write('AHFRTG\n')`` (i.e. ``"f.write('AHFRTG\n')\r\n".encode()``) might be sufficient.

Comment: The above gave me the same result as the original Ie. the two strings combined.

Comment: Did the file get created? What content did it have?

Comment: Yes, the file got created, with ONLY ONE line containing: AHFRTG112121

Comment: the latter 2 lines didn't specify filename. it might be throwing errors. but you didn't get from serialport.

Comment: Lei Yang, sorry I don't understand your comment...

Comment: I think I missed one level of indirection. Does ``"f.write('AHFRTG\\r\\n')\r\n".encode()`` work? (Note the escaped CLRF in the content.)

Comment: I still have some difficulty sending the following line:                                                              result = ser.write("for line in open('Read.py', 'r'):").encode())                                    
Maybe further explanation would help: I would like to read a Python script line by line, and send each line (using serial) to an ESP32 REPL.  Lines containing both " and ' and need to be terminated with a CRLF are the problems.

Comment: That seems like quite a different problem. You might want to create a new question for that.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: You need to include CRLF for *both* the remote process *and* the file.

---

Right now there is only a CRLF passed to the remote process. The file content itself does not include a CRLF.

```
#       no CRLF is written to file vv
result = ser.write("f.write('AHFRTG')\r\n".encode())
#         CRLF is written to process ^^^^
```

You need to include the CRLF in the file content as well. As you are writing literal source code, the CRLF must appear as a literal of `\` `r` `\` `n` instead of an actual CRLF; this requires escaping each `\`.

```
#           CRLF is written to file vvvvvv but it is escaped in the source code
result = ser.write("f.write('AHFRTG\\r\\n')\r\n".encode())
#         CRLF is written to process ^^^^
```